# Angular form as variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-show

I have a form with a dynamic name containing fields with dynamic names.
I want to show a visual error feedback using `ng-show` if the field is invalid.

But since the field is set using a variable, I need to do something like:

```
ng-show="{{form.name}}.{{form.field.name}}.$dirty && {{form.name}}.{{form.field.name}}.$invalid"
```

How do I do that?

*(The above code is obviously not working)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do it not using interpolation, ng-show doesn't need it:

HTML form

```
<form name="testForm">
     <input name="testInput" value="123">
</form>
```

validation ng-show:

```
 ng-show="testForm.testInput.$dirty && testForm.testInput.$invalid"
```

so, in short just treat the variable name as normal and use it...

Comment: That unfortunately isn't possible, because the objects on which I use the dot notation are from the controller, not from the actual form names. Like I said, the names are set dynamically, so I can't use the literal names of the forms and fields.

Comment: just use the JS variable names...I don't know how to say it any simpler...do not interpolate and dirctly use the variable name.

Comment: If this isn't enough then you are going to need to show your JS code.